# Who discovered the real Jordan form?

Tags: mathematics, linear-algebra

The real Jordan form is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices). I want to know who discovered this form. I searched google academics for a long time but couldn't get an answer.